# How to use jquery to ignore all whitespace to calculate the true total number of text?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to ask, I want to count the number of text in the demo, but ignore all whitespace!
At present, I can only ignore the whitespace before and after the text using trim(), but the whitespace between the text will still be counted. I hope this example The value of console.log in console.log should be 13, the number of words, but now the result will become 17. How can I ignore the white space between the words?

```js
$('.demo').each(function(){
  $(this).text((i, t) => t.trim());
  let textlength = $(this).html().length;
  console.log(textlength);
})
```

```css
.demo{
  white-space:pre;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="demo">
  
lorem  test  demo
  
</p>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the easiest way to do this is to replace all whitespace with nothing.

Firstly, to figure out what is whitespace and what isn't, we can use a regular expression.

```
/\s+/g
```

This means to find any sort of space, globally across the entire string.

Then it's just a matter of calling `.replace()`

```
text.replace(/\s/g, '');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 $('.demo').each(function(){
   $(this).text((i, t) => t.trim());
   let textlength = $(this).html().replace(/\s+/g, '').length;
   console.log(textlength);
 })
```

We can use a regular expression to remove all whitespaces before calculating the length.

Answer (score 1):

You can `match` against all non-whitespace characters. It will produce an array, and you can check its length.

```js
$('.demo').each(function() {
  const re = /[^\s-]/g;
  const match = this.textContent.match(re);
  console.log(match.length);
});
```

```css
.demo{ white-space:pre; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="demo">
  
lorem  test  demo
  
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `string.replaceAll(' ', '')` or `str.replace(/ /g, '')` to remove all spaces in a string. There may still be empty space though, so using trim after replacing is good idea.

```js
$('.demo').each(function(){
  let textTrimmed = $(this).text().replaceAll(' ', '').trim()
  console.log(textTrimmed.length);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="demo">
  
lorem  test  demo
  
</p>
```